# What is PHP's isset equivalent in c# .NET 4 for properties of 'dynamic' objects?

Tags: dynamic, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working with MVC 3 at the moment where I use the ViewBag. I would like to test if one of the properties of the ViewBag has been assigned. I know in PHP you could do isset(variable), but is there something similar in .NET 4?

The scenario is that I am making a nested layout which takes a section title and a section subtitle through the ViewBag. They are seperated by a seperator and the sub title is optional. I don't want to display the seperator if the sub title is not set.

This is how I imagine it where isset would be replaced by the .NET 4 equivelant.

```
@section header 
{
    <h2>@ViewBag.SectionTitle</h2>
    @if(isset(ViewBag.SectionSubTitle)) 
    { 
        <div id="section-title-seperator"> - </div><h3>@ViewBag.SectionSubTitle</h3> 
    }
}
```

Next to the direct answer to my question, I'm also open to alternate solutions (in case I'm abusing the ViewBag).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check if it is `null` like this:

`@if(ViewBag.SectionSubTitle != null)`.

`isset()` in PHP actually just checks if there is a value present. From the manual:

> isset() will return FALSE if testing
>   a variable that has been set to NULL

You can also use [`ViewDataDictionary.ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.containskey.aspx) on your `ViewData` property. Because `ViewData["SectionSubTitle"]` is equavilient to `ViewBag.SectionSubTitle` so in this case you could do:

`@if(ViewData.ContainsKey("SectionSubTitle"))`

Comment: Ahh, ok thanks. BTW, just to ensure, I'm not abusing the ViewBag in this case right?

Comment: I would recommend that you refactor it later on. Get it working first. Don't overuse the ViewBag, consider grouping things into seperate models.

Comment: Do this - `if (@parts[1] != null) cat = parts[1];`